# update image after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have some problems.

On click I rotate image with ajax and save new image. Everything is without page refresh.
And problem is that old image won't refresh and put new refreshed image.

Also new image have same name like the old one.

**QUESTION**

My question is how to update img from folder without page refresh? Only after click class slika-rotiraj.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="slika">
    <div class="slika-obrisi"></div>
    <div class="slika-rotiraj"></div>
    <img src="uploads/87b6f334f30717343acd69f3962142a0_542ad975e424d.jpg" />
</div>
```

**SCRIPT :**

```
$(document).on("click", ".slika-rotiraj", function() {
    var slika = $(this).next("img").attr("src");
    var slika1 = $(this).parent();
    var slika2 = $(this).next("img");
    $(this).next("img").attr("src", slika);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "rotiraj.php",
        data: {
            slika: slika
        },
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean that the image has changed *server-side* and you just want to force the `img` tag to fetch the new state of the image?  Simply setting the `src` should accomplish that:

```
success: function(data) {
    // which is your image?  "slika2"?
    // it's not really obvious, so I'll assume that for now
    $(slika2).attr('src', slika);
}
```

If this isn't refreshing the image, you might add a "cache-breaker" to force it to re-request.  Something as simple as this:

```
success: function(data) {
    $(slika2).attr('src', slika + '?' + new Date().getTime());
}
```

This wouldn't affect anything, it would just innocuously change the URL and force the browser to re-request from the server.

Comment: i appreciate your answer, this one with date works only on first click, I rotate image for 90deg. , so first time it show my image, but on next rotating, won't show

Comment: @NebojsaSapic: Do a little debugging.  Where specifically does it fail?  Is the second click event invoked at all in the code?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  Is this line of code reached at all?  Does the new request have a different URL as intended?  Please be specific.

Comment: Fail happened when I add date, because image in folder is withoud that, and when second time i click on rotate, php failed to open stream because of ? + new Date().getTime() in name

Comment: @NebojsaSapic: The change to the URL shouldn't matter to the server-side resource in this case.  Any unexpected query string values will be ignored.  I suspect something else is wrong that you're not showing.  Don't just assume what's wrong, *debug it*.  Examine the *specific* error that you're seeing.

Comment: I was right, I fix it, because new img src is with ?+new Date(), and in folder is without, i just split "?" and take all before "?", and now it works very well. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @NebojsaSapic: Ah, it sounds like your server-side code was reading the query string unnecessarily :)  Please note for future reference that you may have had (and may still have) a huge security vulnerability in that case.  If you take an exact URL and use it to return a specified file from the file system, a malicious user could craft a URL you haven't thought of which would return system files you *don't want them to see*.  It's best to separate out *only* the exact part of the URL you need and validate that it's a file the user is permitted to access, and only then show it.

Answer (score 1):

Give your  tag an id and set the value of the 'src' attribute inside your success function of the ajax call.

**HTML**

```
<div class="slika">
    <div class="slika-obrisi"></div>
    <div class="slika-rotiraj"></div>
    <img id="myimage" src="uploads/87b6f334f30717343acd69f3962142a0_542ad975e424d.jpg" />
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".slika-rotiraj", function() {
    var slika = $(this).next("img").attr("src");
    var slika1 = $(this).parent();
    var slika2 = $(this).next("img");
    $(this).next("img").attr("src", slika);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "rotiraj.php",
        data: {
            slika: slika
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#myimage").attr('src', data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'm appreciate, but not working, it won't refresh image

Comment: @NebojsaSapic what are you returning from your PHP script (rotiraj.php)?  Can you add it to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this if the image has always the same name:

```
$('.slika img').attr('src', 'new path to image');
```

otherwise:

```
$('.slika img').attr('src', 'new path to image' + '?_=' + new Date().getTime());
```